# iOS: Multiply two values

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm making my first iOS app. I simply want to multiply the value from pressureField with temperatureField.
I used a helloiPhone.app to get things going.  So everything is working if I use one field, but I don't know how to set the value of h to two multiplied vars.

Here's what my mainview.m looks like:

```
- (void) sayHello: (id) sender {
    h = 23;
    helloLabel.text =
        [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", h];
    [pressureField resignFirstResponder];
    [tempField resignFirstResponder];
    tempField.text = @"";
    pressureField.text = @"";
}
```

I'm NEW to Objective C...so be easy on me. I'm just hobbying. :)

Comment: Incidentally, whilst you've already accepted my answer, it should be noted there was a typo in the code. (Now fixed.) :-)

Comment: Yeah, I worked it out myself. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're talking about how to get the values and convert them to a numeric format, then something like the following should do the trick...

```
// Grab the values from the UITextFields.
float pressureValue = [[pressureField text] floatValue];
float temperatureValue = [[temperatureField text] floatValue];

// Multiply them.
float h = pressureValue * temperatureValue;
```

You *should* be able to simply replace your initial `h = 23;` line with the above. (*That said, I've not checked the above in a compiler, but it's pretty simple so it should be OK.*) :-)

What you're doing here is getting the textual value from the UITextFields (that you've presumably set up as IBOutlets in your interface file), which are supplied as a [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) pointer via the [UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html) `text` method. We're then using the NSString `floatValue` method to obtain the value in a suitable numeric format.

Incidentally, I'd **really** recommend a good read of Apple's class reference documentation (such as the UITextField & NSString docs linked above) - it's very good quality and you'll learn a lot from simply looking at some of the available methods.

Comment: Thanks! It's hard to know where to start when picking this up from nothing! I'll look at that. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin Hope it goes well - Objective-C (and indeed the UIKit & Cocoa frameworks) are really nice once you get used to the way things are done. :-)

Comment: not working in my case!!.. try multiplying 856887.4 and 58 in UITextfileld and check with the calculator any... @JohnParker

Comment: @ios_dev '58' isn't a float, '58.0' is. Are you sure you're not multiplying a float by an int?